# How to get private videos or unlisted videos from youtube api using flutter?

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-api

Am developing flutter application I have uploading videos as a private through the youTube API. How do we get all private or unlisted videos from YouTube API. If anyone can help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show some code...

Comment: Isn't [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint with [`forMine=true`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) (so using OAuth) solving your issue?